# Moldura distorcida no CSS para por vídeo em cima

Tags: css, html5, css3

Como eu criaria uma moldura estilizada no css? Quero colocar um vídeo do youtube no meu site, mas no fundo gostaria de fazer uma moldura estilizada como tentei desenhar na imagem abaixo, com alguma cor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber como eu 'desenho' isso no css, eu sei fazer o quadrado, mas não consigo fazer distorcer sabe?

```
 <style type="text/css">

div.retangulo {
 line-height:0;
 width:200px;
 height:160px;
 border: 25px solid #00f;
 }



</style>
```

Comment: Aqui tem uns links pra vc ver como pode ser feito: https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/propriedades-css-para-estilizacao-de-bordas.php, https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/css3-bordas-com-imagens.php, https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/molduras.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem um modelo usando `pseudo-elemento` em um box que vai ter o `iframe` do vídeo dentro. O pulo do gato é usar `transform: skew(15deg, 5deg);` no pseudo elemento do box isso vai "entortar" o elemento na forma que vc quiser. Vc pode brincar com esses `deg` para ver o que mais te agrada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  
.box {
  margin-top: 50px;

  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 600px;
  height: 355px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: skew(15deg, 5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g76sAYHhEus" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: aí que me refiro..

Answer (score 3):

Ricardo, você pode usar os poligonos para fazer isso.

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
    <style>
#imagem {
    background: red;
    width: 240px;
    height: 144px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
#moldura {
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 90% 30%, 90% 10%, 20% 10%, 0% 0%, 10% 70%, 10% 90%, 80% 90%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 90% 30%, 90% 10%, 20% 10%, 0% 0%, 10% 70%, 10% 90%, 80% 90%);
}
    </style>
    <div id="moldura">
        <div id="imagem">

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Resultado]

Este site pode te ajudar: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: que baita ferramenta bicho

Comment: Sim, você cria uma div moldura e dentro dela vai o vídeo, e a moldura você modela com este método.

Comment: Ótima referencia RickPro!